# Crash on writeToFile

Tags: objective-c, writetofile

I'm using quite a simple method of storing file names in a text file. For some reason when I initiate the writeToFile I get a crash:

```
pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New FileName - %@.png", identifier];  
NSString *currentContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSString *newContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:::%@",currentContents, pathString];
NSData *newData = [newContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[newData writeToFile:saveFilePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
```

It reads the file, places it's contents into a variable called currentContents, then adds the new string to the file, and re-writes it. What's going wrong here.

Without the writeToFile line it works, with it, I get a crash.

Origin of saveFilePath

```
NSString *saveDocument = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SavedFile.txt"];
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
saveFilePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveDocument];
```

An NSLog of saveFilePath reveals a correct path

Comment: You should use `-[NSData writeToURL:options:error:]` as Apple recommends the use of `NSURL` objects over `NSString` objects when dealing with file paths. By the way, you have a syntax error on the first line.

Comment: Ah you're referring to the comma, that was done during my anonymising process, my original code has the comma there lol. Right, I'll try that NSURL instead of the NSString

Comment: error:nil should be error:NULL

Comment: @onnoweb Error persists on your suggestion too.

Comment: Where is saveFilePath coming from?

Comment: @onnoweb updated the question with it.

Comment: Any message from the console on crash?

Comment: Nope, just crash. It's irritating, even on the silliest mistakes you get a large console printout of why it's not working, on this, nothing.

Comment: 1. Does it crash actually DURING the writeToFile (or after it sometime)? 2. What kind of crash/what does the console say? There's nothing obviously wrong in your code as posted.

Comment: I am reading and writing to a few files, maybe I have to 'close' a file read before writing to it? I'm not sure how I'd do this though.

Comment: @quixoto - like I said, removing the line means it works, adding the line means it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the file wasn't writing was because of an unallocated variable:

```
NSString *currentContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

should have been:

```
NSString *currentContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:saveFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might actually be a missing null character (`'\0'`) at the end of your NSData object. So you finally end up with messed up data. You might want to use `-writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` on your new string right away anyway.